# How to iterate and extract single objects from an array of objects to render in React

Tags: arrays, reactjs, api, object, render

I'm getting some data from an API that's coming as an array of objects and want to extract them and destructure them so I can use them to render a component in React. I have achieved something somewaht but this way I'm not KISS and also to render it is creating the item 6 times for each one of them so I have 24divs.

Data is coming like this, "hourly" array with 48 objects. I already slice the array to only use six as that all I need.

```
"hourly": [
{
  "dt": 1618315200,
  "temp": 282.58,
  "feels_like": 280.4,
  "pressure": 1019,
  "humidity": 68,
  "dew_point": 276.98,
  "uvi": 1.4,
  "clouds": 19,
  "visibility": 306,
  "wind_speed": 4.12,
  "wind_deg": 296,
  "wind_gust": 7.33,
  "weather": [
    {
      "id": 801,
      "main": "Clouds",
      "description": "few clouds",
      "icon": "02d"
    }
  ],
  "pop": 0
},
...
```

This is what I got inside my return and within section tags which does work but I don't think is the best way to do it, also it's a nightmare to style it properly as it creates six items each time:

```
<div className="weather-info-extra">
    {shortedArr.map((i, index) => (
      <div key={index}>
        {new Date(i.dt * 1000).toLocaleTimeString([], {
          timeZone: timezone,
          hour: '2-digit',
          minute: '2-digit',
          hour12: true,
        })}
      </div>
    ))}
    {shortedArr.map((i, index) => (
      <div key={index}>{i.weather.map(w => w.description)}</div>
    ))}
    {shortedArr.map((i, index) => (
      <div key={index}>{i.temp} C</div>
    ))}
    {shortedArr.map((i, index) => (
      <div key={index}>
        <p>Rain</p>
        {i.pop}%
      </div>
    ))}
  </div>
```

I know there's a very obvious way that I'm missing to get each object from the array so I could render it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re right that you can do this more efficiently. You only need to map once. You can use a fragment to encase the multiple elements, this fragment is never rendered but allows you to have multiple children.

```
shortArray.map((data, index) => (
    <React.Fragment key={index}>
        <div>{data.time}</div>
        <div>{data.weather}</div>
        // anything else you want rendered
    <React.Fragment />
));
```

There’s no need for you to map this array multiple times.

Just a side note, fragments that don't need keys can be written as empty tags in JSX:

`<> /** React fragment code here */ </>`

Comment: Nice answer, but this will produce an error due to no unique "key" prop. 
Change the fragment to a keyed fragment or keyed div and you'll get my upvote 

Comment: You're right @RoMilton I've updated it

Comment: Holly saints man! That was spoooot on! So straightforward, I knew there was a better way and I was headed on the right direction just for the life of me couldn't figure it out last night haha! Thank you!!!